# CSS positioning changed when browser resizes or on smaller screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I have a website and when the user logs in they can click on their username and a box under it will appear using jQuery. The problem is the box is positioned according to my browser, and I don't know how to make it right.

The css code I am using to position it:

```
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 116px;
```

If you visit the site you will understand better, login with

website: codexvideos.com

Image how it looks when it's correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOBiy.png

This is how it looks on smaller screens, resized screens, or other browsers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmMh6.png

Please don't post any comments or change the avatar etc.

Comment: have you tried using position: static to see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: If i change it to static then it goes behind the white crumbbar and becomes positioned wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. So, add `position: relative` to your div#wrap declaration and adjust the left position of the drop element accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone and esp. Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

you need to position the menu inside a wrapper and then set the `css to left: 0px; top: 30px;` <-- depending on the height of the top menu item.

Comment: <li style="position: relative;" ><a title="tester's Profile" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" href="./memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&amp;u=203" class="user_photo"><img src="./download/file.php?avatar=203_1333040397.png" width="auto" height="26" alt="User avatar"></a></li>

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and help, but I solved it from Andrews help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set the parent div of the absolute positioned element to position: relative, then the absolute positioning will be based of that element and not the the body of the document.

```
.user_bar { 
     position: relative;
}
```

And then set the absolute positioned element to something like:

```
left: 34px;
top: 34px;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked too, but I chose Andrews answer since he elaborated more :) I know i didn't ask for the definition but his answer was more detailed.